# Ubuntu wsl2 in windows, my /etc/fonts/fonts.conf keeps reloading

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, configuration

For some reason my /etc/fonts/fonts.conf keeps reloading back to an initial version loosing my changes. It happens almost immediately. It is on my Ubuntu wsl2 in windows. Any tips or tricks to fix? How do I fix?

I've used vi and pico both with sudo.